# Is it possible to interrogate the Flow Designer objects?

Tags: metadata, visual-workflow

I've seen [Visual Workflow](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Visual_Workflow) and how flows and processes can be created in the flash tool. But after these are created, can they be interrogated from the SObject or metadata API?

There is `ProcessInstanceStep` in 'standard and custom objects' and `Flow` in 'metadata types and components' but I think the former is for approvals and the latter is very sparse. Also saw `0P0` from [Daniel Ballinger](http://www.fishofprey.com/2011/09/obscure-salesforce-object-key-prefixes.html)'s list but no sign of the rest.

Answer (score 3):

Some rummaging around in the XML transmitted by the flow designer resulted in two Ids: `300b0000000L55S` and `301b0000000L3Pk`.

The first one with prefix `300` was an `InteractionDefinition`.

The second with prefix `301` was an `InteractionDefinitionVersion`.

Got this from `Id.valueOf('300b0000000L55S').getSObjectType()`

`Schema.SObjectType.InteractionDefinition.fields` can't query them!

[image]

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMgupTNUV0E&t=1m1s

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Apex controller if you want a Visualforce page to have access to Flow variables.  And you can also have the Flow call an Apex plug-in with access to Flow variables.  Will one of these work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can now access the flow objects using the Tooling API.

[FlowDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flowdefinition.htm) and [Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_flow.htm) will give you most of what you need. Especially in the Metadata fields.